# A good software to compress (archive) files to lesser size at possible

Tags: compression

I'm looking for a software to compress (archive) files to lesser size at possible.
I downloaded an `zip` file that was `10 MB` but after exracting became `1 GB` !!! The compression was wonderful.
But I have no idea with which software it would be compressed.
I tested archiving files with winrar and 7zip but the size of archived file is almost the same.

which software compress files better ? and is there any detail to compress files more ?

Comment: You'll get useful answers if, and only if, you give some details about the type of information you're trying to compress. Completely different methods are used to compress text, audio, or programs.

Comment: For example video files. The file I mentioned in the question was archive of almost 20 video file

Comment: 7zip: `7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on big_file.7z big_file`

Answer (score 3):

The extreme compression ratio you saw is not a property of the compression software or algorithm, but rather a property of the data fed to it.

RAR and ZIP compression can achieve similar ratios if the input data is, for example, mostly nothing but a long string of the same byte.

Very little general purpose improvement is possible over RAR or ZIP; 7zip / xz offer a little better compression, but mostly by virtue of running the same process with more memory consumed.